# Rendering greyish textures instead of in color

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

I'm porting a bindless textures example from ch11 of Superbible 7th ed., p.557. The objects render fine, however, as you can notice in the uploaded gifs the color is grey in the results that I'm getting.  I'd like to get the color working on each object.  Any ideas what could be causing the problem?  Thank you.

expected output:

[image: expected output]

output I am getting:

[image]

support files: [bindlesstexures_support.zip](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt11/bindlesstexures_support.zip)

source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import ctypes

fullscreen = True
sys.path.append("./shared")

from sbmloader import SBMObject
#from ktxloader import KTXObject
#from textoverlay import OVERLAY_
from shader import shader_load, link_from_shaders

from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, \
    m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
    scale, m3dLookAt, normalize

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    #from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.bindless_texture import glGetTextureHandleARB, glMakeTextureHandleResidentARB
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin
#import glm
identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

myobject = SBMObject()
#ktxobject = KTXObject()
#overlay = OVERLAY_()



NUM_TEXTURES        = 384
TEXTURE_LEVELS      = 5
TEXTURE_SIZE        = (1 << (TEXTURE_LEVELS - 1))


program = GLuint(0)


class textures_:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = GLuint(0)
        self.handle = GLuint64(0)

textures = [textures_() for _ in range(1024)]

class buffers_:
    transformBuffer = GLuint(0)
    textureHandleBuffer = GLuint(0)

buffers = buffers_()

class MATRICES_:
    view = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
    projection = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
    model = [(GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix) for _ in range(NUM_TEXTURES)]

MATRICES = MATRICES_()


import random
random.seed (0x13371337)

def random_uint():
    return random.randint(0, 4294967295)



def load_shaders():
    global program

    shaders = [GLuint(0) for _ in range(2)]

    shaders[0] = shader_load("render.vs.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    shaders[1] = shader_load("render.fs.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    program = link_from_shaders(shaders, 2, True)



class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        global myobject
        global buffers

        tex_data = [0 for _ in range(32 * 32 * 4)]

        mutated_data = [0 for _ in range(32 * 32)]

        for i in range(0, 32):

            for j in range(0, 32):

                tex_data[i * 4 * 32 + j * 4] = (i ^ j) << 3
                tex_data[i * 4 * 32 + j * 4 + 1] = (i ^ j) << 3
                tex_data[i * 4 * 32 + j * 4 + 2] = (i ^ j) << 3


        buffers.transformBuffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffers.transformBuffer)

        glBufferStorage(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
                        ctypes.sizeof(GLfloat) * 16 * 2 * NUM_TEXTURES,
                        None,
                        GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT)

        buffers.textureHandleBuffer = glGenBuffers(1)

        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffers.textureHandleBuffer)

        glBufferStorage(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
                        NUM_TEXTURES * ctypes.sizeof(GLuint64) * 2,
                        None,
                        GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT)

        pHandles = glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, NUM_TEXTURES * ctypes.sizeof(GLuint64) * 2, 
            GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)

        pHandlesp = (GLuint64 * 2 * NUM_TEXTURES).from_address(pHandles)


        for i in range(0, NUM_TEXTURES):

            r = (random_uint() & 0xFCFF3F) << (random_uint() % 12)
            textures[i].name = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i].name)
            glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_LEVELS, GL_RGBA8, TEXTURE_SIZE, TEXTURE_SIZE)


            for j in range(0, 32 * 32):
                mutated_data[j] = ( tex_data[j] & r) | 0x20202020

            glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, TEXTURE_SIZE, TEXTURE_SIZE, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mutated_data)
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            textures[i].handle = glGetTextureHandleARB(textures[i].name)
            glMakeTextureHandleResidentARB(textures[i].handle)
            pHandlesp[i][0] = textures[i].handle

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER)

        load_shaders()

        myobject.load("torus_nrms_tc.sbm")


    def display(self):

        currentTime = time.time()

        last_time = 0.0
        total_time = 0.0

        f = currentTime

        proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(70.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 500.0);    


        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, [0.0,0.0,0.0])
        glClearBufferfi(GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, 0, 1.0, 0)

        glFinish()

        glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, buffers.transformBuffer)

        pMatrices = glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, ctypes.sizeof(GLfloat) * 16 * (NUM_TEXTURES+2), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)

        pMatricesp = (GLfloat * 16 * (NUM_TEXTURES+2)).from_address(pMatrices)

        T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0.0, 0.0, -80.0)

        pMatricesp[0] = T 
        pMatricesp[1] = proj_matrix

        angle = f
        angle2 = 0.7 * f
        angle3 = 0.1 * f

        for i in range (2, NUM_TEXTURES+2):

            T1 = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dTranslateMatrix44(T1, (i % 32) * 4.0 - 62.0, (i >> 5) * 6.0 - 33.0, 15.0 * sin(angle * 0.19) + 3.0 * cos(angle2 * 6.26) + 40.0 * sin(angle3))

            RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, angle * m3dDegToRad(130.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

            RZ = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dRotationMatrix44(RZ, angle * m3dDegToRad(140.0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

            pMatricesp[i] = m3dMultiply(T1, m3dMultiply(RX, RZ))

            angle += 1.0
            angle2 += 4.1
            angle3 += 0.01

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER)

        glFinish()

        glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, buffers.textureHandleBuffer)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        glUseProgram(program)

        myobject.render(NUM_TEXTURES)

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle
            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):
        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    glutInitContextVersion(4,4)
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE)    

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Bindless Textures')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
    fullscreen = False
    #glutFullScreen()
    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)
    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)
    scene.init()
    glutMainLoop()
```

porting attempt from: [bindlesstex.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/bindlesstex/bindlesstex.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues. The first issue is in the transformation of the texture data:

> ```py
> for j in range(0, 32 * 32):
>    mutated_data[j] = ( tex_data[j] & r) | 0x20202020
> ```

See the original c++ code:

> ```cpp
> mutated_data[j] = (((unsigned int *)tex_data)[j] & r) | 0x20202020;
> ```

In the c++ code `unsigned char tex_data[];` is cast to `(unsigned int *)`. Thus 4 elements of the byte array are read at once.

In python you've to reinterpret the array by using [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html):

```py
mutated_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(tex_data, dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
for j in range(0, 32 * 32):
    mutated_data[j] = (mutated_data[j] & r) | 0x20202020
```

The 2nd issue is, that before the two-dimensional texture image is specified, you've to interpret the array of type `unsigned int` as an array of bytes:

```py
byte_buffer = np.frombuffer(mutated_data, dtype=np.byte)
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, TEXTURE_SIZE, TEXTURE_SIZE, GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byte_buffer)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, great insight, read of the source code.  Thank you so much!